# Branch.io SDK can't initialize on Android build in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, branch.io

Branch.io sdk for Unity3d not initialized on Android build. I am using is for deeplinking, but as I see by debug logs it's not even initilized on app start (normally in iOS build I see some logging, but Android is empty). I am using latest Branch.io sdk and Unity3d 2018.3.9f1

What I realised is that asset standard "Update AndroidManifest" button doesn't works on a prefab "BranchPrefab". That just do nothing. I had tried different combinations to set manifest manually using docs(which is seems not actual)/samples projects/forums, but had no results.
I have contacted branch.io support, but they wasn't useful at all. They provided me "fixed" manifest which not actually work. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.myproject.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:name=".SampleBranchApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Branch init -->
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
                android:value="key_live_my_key_here"/>
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <!-- AppLink example -->
            <!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"
                           tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                        android:host="tdetectives.app.link"
                        android:scheme="https"/>
                <data
                        android:host="tdetectives-alternate.app.link"
                        android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                        android:host="open"
                        android:scheme="tdetectives"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Branch install referrer tracking (optional) -->
        <receiver
                android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As a result deeplink doesn't work, dynamic link creation and sharing doesn't work as well, sdk not initialised...

**UPDATED**
After many hours spent I found that branch sdk didn't merge it's manifest to the main manifest and that's why resources wasn't loaded. Seems this works only when there are no main manifest at all.
After doing a trick automatic manifest update did this:

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.myapp.app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:name="io.branch.unity.BranchUnityApp">
    <!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
         UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
         notification data payloads in the background. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:host="open" android:scheme="myAppUrlScheme" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.app.link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp-alternate.app.link" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService" android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_my_key" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>```

For now branch sdk initialise well, deeplink sharing works, but not the opening the app by deeplink click. So, if the app is running in background and I click the deeplink app just restarts without providing the parameters. If app is closed, that just do nothing (app attempts to start, but stacks)

Seems there is some conflict with activities from Firebase Messaging. I am not good with that, may be I am wrong.

Any suggestions?
````

Comment: How can you test this?

Comment: Many ways to test, but normally I receive the debug log on start with a parameters. If app wasn't opened by deeplink click there will be just empty dictionary. Another way is to try to share a deeplink - it will be stopped if branch not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Missing line

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode"
            android:value="false" /> <!-- Set to true to use Branch_Test_Key -->
```

also for testing this you need to upload app on play store or you can use adb command

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <PackageName>/io.branch.referral.InstallListener --es "referrer " "utm_source%3DFacebook"
```

on First Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            // Branch init
            Branch.getInstance().initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        Log.i("BRANCH SDK", referringParams.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.i("BRANCH SDK", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
        } catch (
                Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Just added new updates to main thread text. This line exists now.